# Extract n first consecutive numbers from a string in python

Tags: python, string

Let's consider this string :

```
st = 'text1text6253text'
```

How could I please extract the two first consecutive figures ?

**Expected output** :

```
62
```

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do it?

Comment: You can consider string as an array of chars, so use array slicing. For example ```st[3:9]``` will return new string which contains from 3rd to 9th char excluded.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I've just no idea how to do this
@ Harut Hunanyan thanks for your advice, but how could I find the positions I need ?

Comment: In order to improve my future questions, why do I have so many down votes ? I thought my question was clear, with a simple example and an expected output

Comment: This isn't the type of question you ask in stackoverflow, people don't like it.

Comment:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/476

Comment: I would in the future make things as clear as possible.  Explain what you have tried.  Show some bit of code so they know your making an effort.

Comment: For the question...  I would loop through the string as a char array.  Check if the char is a number of type int.  If yes then check the next item in the array if the arrays length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use regex with `\d{2}`and return that, or go over the string:

```
st = 'text1text6253text'
for i in range(len(st)-1):
    if st[i].isdigit() and st[i+1].isdigit():
        print(st[i]+st[i+1])
        break
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I don't understand : why using a return without a function ? It seems not working when I tested

Comment: yeah i just gave it as an example, you can just print it instead of returning

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
def find_con(n, s):
    result = re.search('\d{%s}'%n, s)
    return result.group(0) if result else result

st = 'text1text6253text'
print(find_con(2, st))
```

Comment: why was this downvoted?  using a regex seems like the obvious approach

Comment: correct, its a great tool

Answer (score 0):

```
st = 'text1text6253text'
lst = list(st)
lst2 = []

for i,v in enumerate(lst):
  if lst[i].isdigit() and lst[i+1].isdigit():
    lst2.append(lst[i])
    lst2.append(lst[i+1])

ans = int(lst2[0] + lst2[1])
print(ans)
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your answers, I built a general function that I propose you below :

```
def extract_n_consecutive_numbers(st,nb):
    for i in range(len(st)-nb+1):
        is_numeric = True
        for j in range(nb):
            is_numeric = is_numeric & st[i+j].isdigit()
        if is_numeric :
            output = ""
            for j in range(nb):
                output += st[i+j]
            return output
    return ""
```

Example :

```
extract_n_consecutive_numbers('text1text6253text',2)
Out[1]: 62
```